# Text file colon and space separated file

Tags: java, python, file, octave

I have a file wordTopic.txt.And the file is of the form:

```
208:4 208:1 1049:2 3059:15 73684:10 715:15 6100:7 1129:15 1276:2 722:6 4809:1 726:15 6456:5 3703:10 1634:11 14342:13 13785:15 8930:6 61497:11 5435:15 327:1 327:1 228:8 7186:14 10229:2 13787:15 14683:3 437:7 1232:7 3272:15 127:15 9731:0 2367:6 957:8 957:8 810:15 11952:5 18459:5 35248:6 24209:6 19155:3 364:1 364:1 2550:15 7169:15 10939:15 35249:11 4039:8 21608:13 2612:7 1006:15 1113:15 87090:14 1423:8 2180:3 1375:15 270:9 2309:2 533:11 9204:15 660:16 17071:13
```

Above is one row of the file and each row will have different length

```
wordid:topicid wordid:topicid wordid:topicid........
```

I want only the topic ids to be stored in an array. How can I take the topic id (i.e.) how can I store the number after colon. Topic ids will be from 0 to 19 only.

Comment: I tried using awk script but i coulnt take topic id part for all word id

Comment: And what do you want to use? Python , Java, Octave, since you tagged them? Have you tried anything with these languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can do it as follows :

```
    String text= "208:4 208:1 1049:2 3059:15 73684:10 715:15 6100:7 1129:15";

    List<Integer> topicIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String str: text.split(" ")) {
        topicIds.add(Integer.parseInt(str.split(":")[1]));
    }
```

Comment: Hey whats the 1 at the end can you explain

Comment: @SmashCode str.split(":") creates String[] which holds wordid and topicId. To get the topicId we use [1].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear but i would do something like this in python:

Assuming this is one line and you can read it in:

```
result_list = []
for element in line.split():
    result_list.append(element.split(":")[-1]
```

This way the topic IDs will be stored in a list (array like structure in python)

Answer (score 0):

You can read `topicid` for a row like this:

```
topic_ids = [el.split(':')[1] for el in row.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can simply use regex to solve your problem (in python).

```
import re

text='208:4 208:1 1049:2 3059:15 73684:10 715:15 6100:7 1129:15 1276:2 722:6 4809:1 726:15 6456:5 3703:10 1634:11 14342:13 13785:15 8930:6 61497:11 5435:15 327:1 327:1 228:8 7186:14 10229:2 13787:15 14683:3 437:7 1232:7 3272:15 127:15 9731:0 2367:6 957:8 957:8 810:15 11952:5 18459:5 35248:6 24209:6 19155:3 364:1 364:1 2550:15 7169:15 10939:15 35249:11 4039:8 21608:13 2612:7 1006:15 1113:15 87090:14 1423:8 2180:3 1375:15 270:9 2309:2 533:11 9204:15 660:16 17071:13'

lst=[x[1:] for x in re.findall(":[0-9]*", text)]
```